# Cannot find 'NSEntityDescription' and 'NSManagedObject' in scope

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I'm trying to add `textfield.text` into my CoreData, I'm new to coredata therefore I googled and copied how to do it, but xCode returns an error: `Cannot find 'NSEntityDescription' in scope` and `Cannot find 'NSManagedObject' in scope` is there any easy solution to fix this ?

```swift
    @objc func textFieldDidChange(_ textField: UITextField) {
        print(textField.text ?? "username581293491822")
        let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
        let context = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext
        let entity = NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "Users", in: context)
        let newUser = NSManagedObject(entity: entity!, insertInto: context)
        newUser.setValue(textField.text ?? "username12312235234", forKey: "username")
    }
```

Comment: @JoakimDanielson actually the name is incorrect and I understand your confusion, `        usernameTextfield.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.textFieldDidChange(_:)), for: .editingDidEnd)` its the code in my `viewDidLoad` as you can see its set on `.editingDidEnd` so I guess there will be no problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to add

```
import CoreData
```